# How to apply resizeToAvoidBottomInset to false on specific container/widget, not for whole app?

Tags: flutter

I have few widgets, and i wanted to apply resizeToAvoidBottomInset = false, to only half part of screen/specific container/widget, when keyboard opens, then it can overlap that widget and don't show bottom overflow error.
Don't want to use resizeToAvoidBottomInset in scaffold, or any native method to know when keyboard opens up.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _mq = MediaQuery.of(context);
    final _safeHeight =
        (_mq.size.height - _mq.padding.top - AppBar().preferredSize.height);
    print('inset: ');
    print(_mq.viewInsets.bottom);
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 7, right: 7),
      //   padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: _mq.viewInsets.bottom + 100),
      //  height: (_mq.size.height - _mq.padding.top - AppBar().preferredSize.height) * .5,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            //height: constraints.maxHeight * .06,
            child: Text(
              'Calculate Power Consumption',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Text(
              'Add Items',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6.fontSize),
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
          ),
          Container(
            // height: constraints.maxHeight * .1,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: _mq.size.width * .3,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 6),
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: _itemNameController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Item Name',
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                      hintText: 'eg. bulb',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(20, 20, 30, .3),
                        fontSize: 14,
                      ),
                    ),
                    autofocus: true,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: _mq.size.width * .3,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 6),
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: _itemWattController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Item Watt',
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                      hintText: 'eg. 60',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(20, 20, 30, .3),
                        fontSize: 14,
                      ),
                    ),
                    autofocus: true,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            // height: constraints.maxHeight * .1,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: _mq.size.width * .30,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 6),
                  child: TextField(
                    autofocus: false,
                    controller: _itemUsageController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Usage hrs/day',
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                      hintText: 'eg. 10',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(20, 20, 30, .3),
                        fontSize: 14,
                      ),
                      errorText:
                          (_itemUsageErrText != '') ? _itemUsageErrText : null,
                      errorMaxLines: 2,
                    ),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      _itemUsageErrText = '';
                      setState(() {
                        if (value.isEmpty) {
                          _itemUsageErrText = 'required';
                        }
                        if (int.parse(value) > 24) {
                          _itemUsageErrText = 'Should not greater than 24';
                        }
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: _mq.size.width * .30,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 6),
                  child: TextField(
                    autofocus: false,
                    controller: _noOfDaysController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'No. of days',
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                      hintText: 'eg. 30',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(20, 20, 30, .3),
                        fontSize: 14,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
           Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: _safeHeight * .03),
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _addItems();
              },
              child: Text('Add Item'),
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              textColor: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button.color,
            ),
          ),
          Container(child: ListWidget(items,_safeHeight),height: _safeHeight * .40,),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ListWidget extends StatelessWidget{
  final List <Item> items;
  final _safeHeight;
  ListWidget(this.items,this._safeHeight);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height);
    print(MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom);
     return Scaffold(
       resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      // resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
       body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (ctx,constraints){
          print('constr: ${constraints.maxHeight}');
         return Container(
             //  height:200,
              child: ListView(
                children: items.map((itm) {
                  return Card(
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Text(itm.name),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            );
       }),  
       
     );
  }
}
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only other think I could think to try is to wrap the container the contains the list widget with an expanded.

Comment: its better option , expanded/flexible.

Answer (score -1):

The only to change to resize property is to do it in the Scaffold.

My best recommendation would be to convert your containers into widgets with Scaffolds and set it there.

Honestly, I would do this just for the sake of readability.

Comment: I m a beginner in mob dev , still learning.
I tried putting last container which contains listview, in to separate class having scaffold widget, and then i used that class in place of container. and put resizeToAvoidBottomInset =false , but even then when i open keyboard it give overflow error.
i just wanted bottom listview part to be not try to resize, if it hide by keyboard it will be okay.

Comment: That's because, the overflow is with the column widget that contains all of your containers.  Try wrapping your column with a SingleChildScrollView

Comment: I know wrapping SingleChildScrollView can solve it, but it will scroll whole page. i just want specific part of screen to be not effected by keyboard. specially bottom half.
but now found some solution. using viewinsetsbottom value, to resize container height when keyboard opens.